# Why does console.log display array different than alert?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

I wrote a function that filters objects in a specific manner (grouped by key but only consecutive ones, it works fine).

```js
groupBySequentialValues(array, key) {
    let groupName = null;
    let groupIndex = 0;
    let result = []; // keep this in mind!

    array.forEach((el, index) => {
        if (groupName !== array[index][key]) {
            groupName = array[index][key]
            groupIndex++;
            result[groupIndex + '_' + groupName] = []
        }
        result[groupIndex + '_' + groupName].push(el);
    })

    alert(result);
    console.log(result);
}
```

At first the alert shows an empty array, but after the alert is closed, the console log will show the correctly assembled array. (This also happends without the alert of course, this just shows the difference the best)
But I cannot use this array in alerts or in the template (I use it in VueJS to render a list, but its empty like I said).
 Somehow dev tools seems to see its contents but alert/the dom doesnt. 
After declaring the result array as an object (`{}` instead of `[]`) it worked.
Why does dev tools/console log behave this way? Its a debug tool, but when it behaves like this I cannot rely on it as a debugging tool..

Comment: [What is a Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: You may be pushing an object to it but it's still an array with array indexing no?

Comment: It is this ---> `result[groupIndex + '_' + groupName]`

Comment: An array in Javascript is simply an object with special abilities, e.g. being `iterable` and inheriting the `Array.prototype`. As such, you're free to declare any new properties on it just like you would with an object. And that is just what you're doing.

Comment: @Randy Casburn I know whats wrong with my code. Please read the whole question :)

Comment: "_Would be annoying to debug everything with alert though..._" - then use the proper tool - a debugger.

Comment: `alert` is *blocking*, you're aware of that?

Comment: @connexo It doesnt work when I declare it as an array though. 
I know alert blocks the queue. How does this matter? The alert displays nothing, the console log does.

Comment: *But I cannot use this array in alerts or in the template (I use VueJS)* You're never explaing what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: @RandyCasburn console.log is the easiest and most common/popular debugging "tool" there is...

Comment: @connexo Do I need to? I wrote in my question that alert displays nothing but console does. It doesnt really matter what I use it for.

Comment: `console` has specifically implemented abilites to show contents of complex data types. Don't expect comparable output in `alert`. **Never** use `alert` for debugging.

Comment: You are explicitly assigning an empty array, why would it be perfectly fine to push to that? `result[groupIndex + '_' + groupName] = []`. You end up with an array with alot of `string` keys containing an array with one element each.

Comment: @connexo Why wouldnt it be fine to do that? It works fine? You have to tell me, Im here asking for help.

Comment: @connexo No, there can be multiple elements.

Comment: It could be perfectly fine to do that, if that is the result you need, why are you asking a question here? I don't see what you are even asking. *Why does console.log display incorrectly built array?* There is no *incorrectly built array*  in your question or code.

Comment: What do you mean, Im asking a question on StackOverflow, why shouldnt I be asking questions here. I understand the title is missleading. I will change it. But my question is very valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When constructing an object and printing that object to the console, `console.log()` will output the object's own properties and their values. If you `console.log()` the object using the object's `.toString()` method you will receive `[object Object]` in the console. This is the exact result you see in the alert of the object:

```js
const obj = {};
obj['test'] = 'this is a test';
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.toString());
alert(obj);
```

If you create an array and `console.log()` its internal `toString()` method prints the *elements of the array* comma separated with `[]` surrounding them. When `alert()`ing an array, the `.toString()` method is used to print only the array values:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr);
alert(arr);
```

Finally, your code adds properties to an Array Object rather than adding elements to the array. When this occurs, `console.log()` prints this Object  exactly like the first example, but because this is an Array Object, it places `[]` around the properties and their values rather than `{}`. Since the array is *empty* (no elements), it prints `[]` literally.

The code below demonstrates the structure of the Array Object your code creates, shows the number of array elements is zero, shows the Array Object's property names, shows the value associated with that property and finally shows the object in the console.

If you alert the `result` as explained in the previous example, the dialog will be empty because there are no elements in the array.

```js
let groupName = 'test';
let groupIndex = 0;
let el = 'this is a test';
let result = [];

result[groupIndex + '_' + groupName] = []
result[groupIndex + '_' + groupName].push(el);

console.log('Number of elements in result array: ', result.length);
console.log('result Object Property Names: ', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result));
console.log('result Object Property Value: ', result[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(result)[1]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Youre the first one who actually understood and answered my question! Thank you for that. In my project the console log doesnt work like yours, mine outputs the full array,  not an empty one...

Comment: Each platform is different. For instance, in the console of my WebStorm IDE I see exactly what you describe, but in Safari I see what I describe.

Comment: Additionally, in the StackSnippets on this site, the console is sanitized and behaves a bit differently than in some other platforms too.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if you've found it answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: I will!
But this means that ultimately console.log really is a bad tool to use for debugging/testing purposes. (While being the most common/basic one)

Comment: The funny thing is that you can display child elements of such an array but not the full array: https://jsfiddle.net/4ou3dt5v/

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript Array is an array of course, but it is also an Object.

And more, it accept index as string without problem:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(a[0])
console.log(a['0'])
```

Those console.log will output the first value of the array = 1.

So the Array is wide tollerant and that is why it should be used carefully to avoid suprises in a form of very hard to debug bugs.

In your case you should use an Object or a Map.

**UPDATED**

Also consider that the window.alert is very different from console.log.

The window.alert attempt to print a string format of the input, that should be passed as a string, but if it is not, then it is forced.

That mean that this:

```
const x = {}
alert(x)
```

Will print *[object Object]*.
While if you use:

```
console.log(x)
```

You will see:

```
{}
```

And you will be able to browse the object methods and attributes, even the object is empty.

Comment: Then my code should work even with declaring the result as an array but it doesnt. And you didnt answer my question Im afraid.

Comment: If you sue strings as indexes for the array it just works.

Comment: Well it does not in my case. It only works when using console to log the output. I cannot use it in an alert.

Comment: The alert function has a very different signature than the console.log. As the console.log print out objects, alert don't, instead it prints the string representation.